# Highlight hits within attachment content with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, attachment, highlight

I'm having trouble getting ElasticSearch to highlight hits within attachment content indexed using the `elasticsearch-mapper-attachments`.

My data at `/stuff/file` looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "string"
    "name": "string"
    "attachment": "...base 64 encoded file"
}
```

My mapper configuration put to `/stuff/file/_mapper` looks like this:

```
{
    "file" : {
        "properties" : {
            "attachment" : {  
                "type" : "attachment",
                "path" : "full",
                "fields": {
                    "name": { "store": true },
                    "title": { "store": true },
                    "content": { "store": true },
                    "attachment": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                        "store": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I query it at `/stuff/_mapper/file` I get this returned:

```
{
   "stuff":{
      "mappings":{
         "file":{
            "properties":{
               "attachment":{
                  "type":"attachment",
                  "path":"full",
                  "fields":{
                     "attachment":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "author":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "title":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "name":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "date":{
                        "type":"date",
                        "format":"dateOptionalTime"
                     },
                     "keywords":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "content_type":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "content_length":{
                        "type":"integer"
                     },
                     "language":{
                        "type":"string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "id":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "name":{
                  "type":"string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And my query looks like this:

```
{
    "size": 30,
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "{{.Query}}",
            "operator": "and",
            "fields": ["id", "name^4", "attachment"],
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "minimum_should_match": "80%"
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "attachment": { }
        }
    }
}
```

When I search for a term that is in the attachment, it returns the correct result but there is no highlighting.  There was a similar question from a few years ago that swapped `attachment` for `file` in a few places but there were comments that this has changed again... What's the right configuration to get the highlighting to work?

Comment: iam having the same problem ... attachment highlighting wont support in elastic search 1.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that you can't overwrite mapper configurations using `PUT`.  You need to delete the existing configuration first (I actually had delete the entire database, `DELETE` on the configuration didn't seem to have any effect).  Once the mapper configuration was actually updated, highlighting works fine.